# AWS ACM renewal issue with DNS method

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-acm

I have ACM certificate which is verified with DNS method. 
Now it's getting issue of renewal. Because domain is pointed with ELB record as CNAME.

How can I add both ELB CNAME and ACM CNAME record to same host?

Comment: ACM's CNAMEs are subdomains (with random characters) of the domain you're trying to verify. They should not conflict - if they do, you're doing something incorrectly.